# Error in finding QDomDocument in c++ code

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt for reading a Xml file in C++ code. I downloaded and installed Qt5 completely. Now, I add this line to my C++ code as a header:

```
#include <QtXml/QDomDocument>
```

even I add its path in command prompt:

```
export CPATH="/home/shirin/qt5"
```

but still receive this error:

```
fatal error: QtXml/QDomDocument: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it, please?

Comment: Did you add xml to your pro file? The component is only available if enabled

Answer (score 3):

Add `QT += xml` into your `.pro` file, `run qmake` and re-build.
Also there is no need for the module in the include: `#include <QDomDocument>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building with `cmake`, the `Xml` package must be found, and the corresponding library `Qt5::Xml` must be linked. (See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) for the complete doc).

Here is an example if you're building a library using Qt with cmake. Note that I add `Core` in the example since it has to be here if you use Qt. Your list of Qt modules might of course be longer.

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Xml REQUIRED)

# ...

add_library(mylib)
target_link_libraries(mylib, Qt5::Core Qt5::Xml)
```

*Note* If `cmake` cannot find the Qt packages, you might have to tweak the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, i.e.

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/Qt /path/to/src
```